Resolving linker problem with explicit object instantiation
I have a quite complicated C++14 cmake-based project, it's not so easy to prepare minimal complete verifiable example. Using boost 1.73 I found the problem with linking on runtime stage on Ubuntu 22.04/23.04. In particular ldd returns something like this:
libboost_regex.so.1.73.0 => not found

Other Boost libraries (like thread, filesystem) are located successfully in the same directory as an application.
libboost_thread.so.1.73.0 => ./libboost_thread.so.1.73.0 

I found that I can fix the problem by explicitly adding global object from regex library, e.g.:
boost::basic_regex<char> fix_linker_issue("");

Library is resolved after that:
libboost_regex.so.1.73.0 => ./libboost_regex.so.1.73.0 

At the same time, default constructed object doesn't help:
boost::basic_regex<char> doesnt_help;

Could someone please explain me the reason how that fix (adding a global object) works?
There's no such problem with more modern Boost 1.84 very likely because regex library became header-only. Adding current directory . to LD_LIBRARY_PATH environmental variable also solves the problem.

The only thing you have to explain is why libboost_regex is found at link time, but not at runtime. This is related to your LD library path (ldconfig, LD_LIBRARY_PATH). The workarounds seem less than interesting in that respect.

@sehe I don't see any related to Boost path in ldconfig, I expect to use all Boost shared libraries from the current directory. Updated question.

Then you need LD_LIBRARY_PATH=. at runtime. Also look at -Wl,rpath and similar runtime path hints (but don't use those when packaging for general distros)

@sehe Probably yes, but I don't understand why it works for other mentioned libs on the same directory and how it relate to instantiated object.

Likely the runtime dependencies are optimized out (due to inlining or just no external symbols depended on)

@sehe in that case such optimization seems broken, because it's not possible to run app until we have all libs resolved

Ah. Check that libboost_regex.so.1.73.0 exists in that same location. Check that indirect requirements are met (ldd libboost_regex.so.1.73.0). By the way, it makes exactly zero sense for boost_thread to be found in "." unless you are already linking that with rpath options. You can check your build scripts to find what causes that.
